# style attribute of XSSFWorkbook cell of Apache POI show compilation errors

Tags: android, apache-poi

I use Apache poi to generate excel data which can be accessed outside the app. I have a problem with creating style. Some methods of the style properties keeps showing error when I added the expected values.

```
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    BorderStyle thin = BorderStyle.THIN;
    short black = IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex();
    CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
    style.setBorderRight(thin);
    style.setRightBorderColor(black);
    style.setBorderBottom(thin);
    style.setBottomBorderColor(black);
    style.setBorderLeft(thin);
    style.setLeftBorderColor(black);
    style.setBorderTop(thin);
    style.setTopBorderColor(black);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER_SELECTION);
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

I have the following errors when I tried to compile the  code:

> error: incompatible types: HorizontalAlignment cannot be converted to
>   short
>
> error: incompatible types: FillPatternType cannot be converted to
>   short
>
> error: incompatible types: BorderStyle cannot be converted to short
>
> error: incompatible types: BorderStyle cannot be converted to short
>
> error: incompatible types: BorderStyle cannot be converted to short
>
> error: incompatible types: BorderStyle cannot be converted to short

Comment: Don't mix jars between Apache POI versions! Remove the older ones, and only run with the latest jars

Comment: @Gagravarr, the Apache POI library I was able to use after many trials was missing the commons-codec library which the application requests each time I try to compile the code. So I borrow this library from one of the Apache POI versions I downloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Gagravarr suggestion, I realised the problem was from mixing two versions of the Apache POI library. There seems to be comflict while trying to build the project. After some digging around the web, I came across a far more simple solution https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/poi-android (written in Kotlin). I just added the maven repository, dependencies and System.setProperties. Then, android studio downloaded the need libraries.